# how to create custom flutter component?

Tags: android, flutter

flutter provides greate components but sometimes the component you want is not available in flutter or any other library. How to create your own component from scratch? How the component is written in a flutter, is it written in the dart, java, kotlin, or c++ ??

Comment: cannot you just `ctl click` on any widget to see its sources?

Comment: I still can't find where the widget call skia Graphic Engine. it is still not clear how all this connects.

Comment: read [RenderObject](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) / [RenderBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html) official documentation